# Why is SignalR dependent on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

So I know upcomping releases of SignalR are being made not to rely on jQuery.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372 - the closed issue to move it away from jQuery.

But why was it dependant on it in the first place? (Obviously from a technical standpoint) Seeing as there seems to be nothing special about jQuery (apart from it exists, in the sense that it *could* make your life easier).

Was this mostly due to the practicalities of jQuery?

Comment: Ask Microsoft. We don't know why they chose to utilize jQuery instead of making it independent. It started out as a open source project by Microsoft employees, and later the company itself picked it up because it saw potential.

Comment: Might tweet Damien Edwards then, however you are assuming that by saying `we` the stackoverflow community, has no members that work a Microsoft....

Comment: I don't know SignalR so I can't tell you what the dependencies are. But when starting a library you need often some common utility functions and because you want to focus on your actual project instead of hassle around with implementing those functions, you will often choose one or more libraries providing those function. It is often better to remove the dependencies later, than having a project that will die because you first need to implement the annoying utility functions.

Comment: With JavaScript, isn't that what copy & paste is for? @t.niese , but I was thinking along those lines

Comment: @CallumLinington If you do Copy&Past then you need to insert the corresponding copyright notices of the other project into your source-code. And you might not want to do this until you are sure that you really just want to use this piece of code. So having a _normal_ dependencies is a better choice. Well you could argue that you could place it in a separate file having the code still separated. But why should you bother about that in the first place.

Comment: Surely you can't copy right functions, especially if you "re-write" them yourself...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The SignalR JS client currently uses jQuery for the following functions:

- Custom events (on objects, not DOM elements)
- Ajax (works on older IE, wrapped in promises, etc.)
- Promises (deferred)
- Misc. utilities

When we remove the jQuery dependency, we'll need replacements for all of these. There are some modern standards supported in ES6 and the latest browsers that will give us some of these things, but others we'll need to create new wrappers for. We may still choose to detect and "light up" on jQuery if it's loaded before us, e.g. to support older IE versions.

Comment: If we have JQuery delivered via CDN and not via nuget. Is there a way to uninstall nuget package while keeping signalR in. At the moment it complains due to dependency so keeping jQuery package in but layout references CDN files.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use .Net Core version which now works without jQuery you can use this. It's SignalR wrapped in NPM module and it doesn't require jQuery. It only locally loads ~5KB necessary functions taken from it https://github.com/DVLP/signalr-no-jquery